# run cron file from terminal in django

Tags: python, django, terminal, cron

Hi i have a django project and i need to run a cron job from terminal

below is my code

```
 import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "noHitter.settings")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query="SELECT age FROM  `Player_myplayer`"
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

when i try to run this on terminal i got the following error

```
 Could not import settings 'noHitter.settings'
```

please suggest where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach of achieving this would be creating a [custom management task](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands), then adding it to the crontab, e.g.

**crontab -e**

```
0 5 * * * ~/path/to/python ~/path/to/manage.py <command_name>
```

Another, more complex way would be to setup a script with the required environment variables, [see this example](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SimpleBashScriptToSetupDevelopmentEnvironment).